# react.component equivalent for styled components return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm making a simple portfolio page and for the same, I have a few icons I want to render for which I have used [Material UI icons](https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/)
Now I added the same custom styling to them and since I'm new to styled-components I did it as follows

```
const iconsArray = [GitHubIcon, LinkedInIcon, CallIcon];
const styledIcons = iconsArray.map(
    (item) => styled(item)`
        //other styles
        :hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    `
);
```

the iconsArray above is made from direct imports from Material UI icons
Now I want to render the icons as

```
{styledIcons.map(styledIcon=>(
    <styledIcon>
        <a href={correspondingLink}>
        </a>
    </styledIcon>
)}
```

This won't work for obvious reasons but I can't access the component even using styledIcon.component like we could for normal react components. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: I know I can do it in different ways but just wanted to check if there's a way around this

Comment: I don't understand whats react.component equivalent means and what are the obvious reasons you talking about. Can you make a sandbox example?

Comment: Moreover, you shouldn't use styled-component with MUI, use MUI styling API for this, that's the reason for picking a components library, so you won't need to use 3rd party or any styling at all.

Comment: So firstly the output for styled components is an object that's why this doesn't work directly. Since react can't directly render objects(each styledIcon here is an object). I have used material ui only for the icons themselves not for styling. I didn't use styled-icons since it seemed a lot more heavyweight. The project is just a personal website not something that is going to be scalable or worrisome to manage so I wanted to try out different libraries